Streamlit - feedback on provided response from Endpoint
I have a Streamlit application that invokes my SageMaker Endpoint and provide response to the user's query. I want to add the feedback to the provided streamlit chat_message. The feedback appears in the chat box and I can fill in my feedback but I cannot retrieve the feedback in my application.
with st.chat_message("assistant", avatar="img/test.png"):
     st.write_stream(streamText(response)) 
     feedback = streamlit_feedback(feedback_type="faces", align="flex-start", optional_text_label="[Optional] Please provide an explanation: ")

if feedback:
     print(feedback)
     st.write('there is a feedback')
     st.markdown('there is a feedback')
     st.write(feedback)
     st.markdown(feedback)
     st.session_state.feedback = feedback

It does not print out anything.  Any thoughts?
